# Automatic Truncation in Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We are capturing data from documents and sometimes we capture more than we can store in our database. I'd like to be able to perform automatic truncation across all entities for string values, I do not transactions to fail due to:

```java
Could not process protect job; exception=org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:223) ...
```

I want to do this all in the one spot. Currently my approach is to use reflection within an interceptor: `org.hibernateEmptyInterceptor` to truncate any `String` members, but I would like to avoid having to do that if there is a solution out there for this already, that doesn't need what feels like a sledge hammer.

We keep getting this error pop up in all sorts of places and we really don't care about losing some data, and I'd like to stop it once and for all. But I don't want to have to edit every single setter we have to do truncation on every `Entity` if I don't have too, as I believe we will easily forget to do this in some place somewhere. I've looked at other approaches but most of them revolve around validation, which I do not want. I do not want to throw a validation error, I want to truncate.

Comment: Have you tried creating an attribute converter?

Comment: Hey thanks that might be an option, I'll have a shot at that.

Comment: You could create custom entity listener  https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-event-listeners/ , will be applied to all entities, a single point. But suppose you still would need reflection to get column length ( from annotation value ? ) and trim strings.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is the size of the data, I think it should throw in MySQL DataException and in oracle SQLException, DataIntegrityViolationException is more for PK and FK issues, you are not trying to insert the object instead of updating it?